# ASP.NET Core pagination and filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pagination, filtering

I have an `ASP.NET Core` application with `EF Core` where I am doing pagination and filter on multiple properties using `LINQ`.
I am trying to get the total items count before pagination and the paginated items with the best way

```
List<User> allUsersList = _dbContext.Users
    .Where(x => x.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(filterWord.ToLower()) ||
                x.LastName.ToLower().Contains(filterWord.ToLower()) ||
                x.Email.ToLower().Contains(filterWord.ToLower()))
    .ToList();  

int totalNumber = allUsersList.Count();      

List<User> paginetedItems = allUsersList
    .Skip((filter.PageNumber - 1) * filter.PageSize) 
    .Take(filter.PageSize).ToList();
```

The problem with this way, is I am not doing an actual server-side pagination.
Another way is to do 2 separate functions one for getting the total count and the other one for getting the paginated items.
But the question is how can I keep the filterWord filtered in one place instead of worring about missing one of the filters everytime.

If non of the optinos above is efficient, how can I do that in the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage Entity Framework deferred evaluation. For example:

```
// This doesn't actually run a DB query
var userQuery = _dbContext.Users
    .Where(x => x.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(filterWord.ToLower()) ||
                x.LastName.ToLower().Contains(filterWord.ToLower()) ||
                x.Email.ToLower().Contains(filterWord.ToLower())); 

// This will run a SELECT COUNT(*) query
int totalNumber = userQuery.Count();      

// And finally, this will return the paginated items
List<User> paginetedItems = userQuery
    .Skip((filter.PageNumber - 1) * filter.PageSize) 
    .Take(filter.PageSize)
    .ToList();
```